# How Apply Visual Basic Multi-Select to Column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not familiar with programming Excel codes, but I was able to find one code to apply the Multi-Select in a DropDown List without repetition. However, it only applies to that one cell, so I am left with going through each cell to apply that rule to each separate cell. I would like to apply this rule-coding to the column if that's possible!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
    ' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Target.Address = "$E$13" Then

        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value

            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
                Else:
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                End If
            End If

        End If

    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include the code as text not as an image. use backticks ` to use markdown

Comment: You want to check your `Target` (the cell that changed) against a range. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27183196/4717755) gives good guidance to accomplish it.

Comment: @erazorv4 I have adjusted it.

Comment: @PeterT I attempted to add this and adjust the Range to my cell. It says there is a compile error: Ambiguous name detected: Worsheet_Change

Comment: You can only have one instance of worksheet_change in the sheet module.

Comment: @BigBen how would I adjust it?

Comment: Check if `Target.Column = something` instead of `Target.Address`.

Comment: So...
If Target.Column = "E" Then 
?? @BigBen

Comment: If `Target.Column = 5`. It returns the column number, not a letter.

Comment: I will check this as accepted once I get rep. @BigBen

Comment: Well, you can't check a comment... I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Perfect! @BigBen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking `Target.Address`, you want to check `Target.Column`.

```
If Target.Column = 5 Then
```

You might also want to check that `Target` is just *one* column. For example, `Range("E5:G5").Column` will still return `5`.

You can do this with:

```
If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
```

Or together:

```
If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 5 Then
```