# How to automaticaly run vba code after exit

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel which design for if the target value is not met H1 cell automatically blink.Can stop this vba code by entering 1 in D1 cell.But after I delete 1 from the D1 cell again it doest blink again until I run the macro by manually.
below is the code in Module

```
    Sub BlinkCell()
Dim CellToBlink As Range
Set CellToBlink = Range("H1")
Do While Range("F20").Value < Range("B1").Value
    CellToBlink.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    CellToBlink.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    CellToBlink.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    DoEvents
If Range("D1").Value = 1 Then Exit Do

Loop

If Range("F20").Value >= Range("B1").Value Then
CellToBlink.Interior.Color = vbWhite
End If

End Sub
```

Below is the Code in worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B5:E19")) Is Nothing Then
Range("D1").ClearContents
Call BlinkCell
End If
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: It's not blinking again because your `Worksheet_Change` event code is not checking for a change in cell D1. Check for that and if the value is deleted, you can re-enable the blinking. Personally, I would probably not blink the cell but would set the background color to red until the value are at the acceptable target.

Comment: how to edit this code for check d1 again

Comment: Please research the `Worksheet_Change` event as suggested by @petert

Comment: please let me know the updated code.This code copied from web.I dont know vba to edit.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27182987/4717755) to see how the code can check for multiple cells that have changed. If you're in the VBA editor and using the code, understanding at least a little about it will dramatically help you perform your work with in the future. In the answer link above, you'll just add anothing `If` statement to look at cell D1. So the modification to your code is very minor. Give it a try and then come back and ask more questions if you get stuck.

Comment: hard to understand it