How to apply VBA code enabling multiple drop-down selection to a range of cells
I am using the code at the end of this message to enable multiple option selection from a drop down list in excel. The code works fine, but if I want it to apply to more than 1 cell, i need to manually add in the code : Or Target.Address = "$AR$4" Then Or ...same over and over.
I have 1000 cells, all in the same column that i need the muti-select macro to work. How do I change the code to allow function on a range, rather than by cell?
Thank you!
PS I am a complete newbie so need either the direct change in code or detailed instructions, as I don't know how to work the development function in excel on my own.
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$AR$2" Or Target.Address = "$AR$3" Or 
Target.Address = "$AR$4" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing 
Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182541/worksheet-change-targeting-multiple-cells-simultaneously

Thanks @SJR i've edited my post :)

What does muti-select macro mean? You can use If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AR2:AR1000")) Is Nothing Then to check if Target is within a range.
